# Google Spreadsheet - MIX several column values

Tags: google-sheets

Hello I have 3 or more columns in Google Spreadsheet like this:

| CITY | SEASON | COLOR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ROME | SUMMER | WHITE |
| PARIS | SPRING | BLUE |
| LONDON | WINTER |  |

What I need is a combination of all values in the 3 columns such as:

- ROME SUMMER WHITE
- ROME SUMMER BLUE
- ROME SPRING WHITE
- ROME SPRING BLUE
- ROME WINTER WHITE
- ROME WINTER BLUE
- PARIS SUMMER WHITE
- PARIS SUMMER BLUE
- PARIS SPRING WHITE
- PARIS SPRING BLUE
- PARIS WINTER WHITE
- PARIS WINTER BLUE
- LONDON SUMMER WHITE
- etc...

Consider that columns could be 2 or more.
Have any solution? Thank you!

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/125018/186471

Comment: Would you be open to the possibility of using [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the header "City" is in A1 and the rest of your raw data example follows suit (i.e., everything is in A1:C), this should do it:

`=ArrayFormula(FLATTEN(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")&" "&TRANSPOSE(FLATTEN(FILTER(B2:B,B2:B<>"")&" "&TRANSPOSE(FILTER(C2:C,C2:C<>""))))))`

`FILTER` limits each range to only those that contain data.

`TRANSPOSE` in each case flips one of the vertical ranges to a horizontal one to form a virtual grid that can be filled with combinations.

The rundown here is that ColB and ColC words are concatenated with a space first. `FLATTEN` then turns that grid of combinations into a single column (as if you only ever had ColA and ColB-new). Then this process is repeated, with ColA and the newly formed ColB-C combos, which are once more `FLATTEN`ed to form the final one-column list.

Comment: Erik you are a MASTER! Thank you

Comment: Happy to help, Rendall. And thanks for closing the loop by marking the post as "Best Answer." That will allow contributors to see at a glance without leaving the main listings page which issues have been fully resolved already; and it will help future site visitors with a similar question more quickly find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `join` built in function of GoogleSheets like so:

```
=JOIN(" ",A1,B1,C1)
```

you can see the documentation for the join function [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en)

> JOIN function
>
> Concatenates the elements of one or more one-dimensional arrays using a specified >delimiter.

Alternatively, if you wish to do this for multiple rows at the same time, you may use an [Array formula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) like so:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1&" "&B1&" "&C1)
```

Comment: No that is not the result I need. This is like concatenate but I want all cells mix together in all possible combinations